# Touch screen supported API for desktop development in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, touch, awt, multi-touch

I'm developing a system that will eventually be implemented on a touch-screen supported machines such as HP Touchsmart.

Are there any relevant references in java swing api that support flicking pages to scroll up/down (such as in iphone/android phone)? Any general references to any swing api that support touch/multi-touch are also appreciated.

Thanks!

PV

Comment: This is pretty old by now but came up in a Google alert...
Swing isn't optimized for touch, but we modeled Codename One based on a lot of the ideas of Swing and it is optimized for touch and allows building desktop applications as well as mobile and pretty much everything: https://www.codenameone.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should look for some kind of mouse gesture library since Java will see touchscreen just like any other "mouse". It would be nice to see Swing L&F specialized for touch screens that takes care of mouse gestures and size of the controls.

Comment: thanks aco, I`ve looked into some mouse gesture libraries and still yet have to play around with it.